# No option to login to RealVNC Viewer

Tags: realvnc

I have been using RealVNC Viewer to login to my remote desktop. Today I switched to a new laptop, but when I installed VNC Viewer on this new laptop, I do not see an option to login? I have the same vncviewer version installed on the previous laptop and it shows me this option. Do you know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the answer was mucked up registry key entries. I followed the instructions on the below help article and it solved the issue.

https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002250957-Completely-Removing-VNC-Connect#removing-vnc-connect-configuration-and-other-files-0-4